# Pandas: Rolling Mean and ignore NaN

Tags: python, pandas, python-polars

How does you tell pandas to ignore `NaN` values when calculating a mean? With min periods, pandas will return `NaN` for a number of `min_periods` when it encounters a single `NaN`.

Example:

```
pd.DataFrame({ 'x': [np.nan, 0, 1, 2, 3, np.nan, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]}).rolling(3, min_periods = 3).mean()
```

Result:

```
-1  NaN
0   NaN
1   NaN
2   1.0
3   2.0
4   NaN
5   NaN
6   NaN
7   6.0
8   7.0
9   8.0
```

Desired Result:

```
-1  NaN
0   NaN
1   NaN
2   1.0
3   2.0
4   2.0
5   3.3
6   4.6
7   6.0
8   7.0
9   8.0
```

Comment: Is your desired result correct?

Comment: I believe it is

Comment: Can you explain what the mean of `[3, nan, 5]` should be?  And where is that represented in your desired result?

Comment: Ohh! I see.  You want the mean of the last 3 non-null values.

Answer (score 2):

You want to drop the `np.nan` first then rolling mean.  Afterwards, reindex with the original index and forward fill values to fill the `np.nan`.

```
df.x.dropna().rolling(3).mean().reindex(df.index, method='pad')

0          NaN
1          NaN
2          NaN
3     1.000000
4     2.000000
5     2.000000
6     3.333333
7     4.666667
8     6.000000
9     7.000000
10    8.000000
Name: x, dtype: float64
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it must be NaN until there are 3 valid results. If some of the first values are NaN, this will fail. I have updated the example to showcase this edge case.

Comment: I understand your question now.  I've edited my answer.  Let me know if that suffices

Comment: Wow, clever, thank you! If you have time, it would be great to say about how fast this is compared to the normal rolling. It would be good not to do anything that would be a problem with very large frames.